# How to combine (Logical OR) two images with pillow?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have two binary black and white images (mode=1) in pillow. I'd like to create a new image of the same size that is simply the binary addition of both. In other words, I'd like to do a logical ORing of each pixel.

I've been reading the docs for a while now and can't figure out this seemingly simple task. Any ideas?

Comment: You could load the two images in, retrieve their image data as bytes using `Image.tobytes()`, OR those two together, and then create a new image from the result using `Image.frombytes()`. The alternative of doing multiple `getpixel()` and `putpixel()` calls (or `PixelAccess` via `[x, y]` accesses) to accomplish the same thing would likely be too slow to be practical.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up going with the getpixel() putpixel() approach. I was hoping there was a built in method for this, but at least I have a working solution.

Comment: I'm kind of new to python and had mutability issues with `tobytes()` `frombytes()` which is why I didn't follow through with that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ImageChops.add()](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.0/reference/ImageChops.html?highlight=add#PIL.ImageChops.add) method:

> PIL.ImageChops.add(image1, image2, scale=1.0, offset=0)[source]
>   Adds two images, dividing the result by scale and adding the offset. If omitted, scale defaults to 1.0, and offset to 0.0.

```
out = ((image1 + image2) / scale + offset)

Return type:    Image
```

This will let you create a composite image that looks like an OR operation between two images.